# how to customize standard gtk_search_bar

Tags: gtk3

For adding search bar to the GTK3 app (in C). I'm using the following cooe:

```
pad->priv->searchbar = GTK_SEARCH_BAR (gtk_search_bar_new ());
gtk_search_bar_set_show_close_button (pad->priv->searchbar, TRUE);

GtkSearchEntry *searchentry = GTK_SEARCH_ENTRY (gtk_search_entry_new ());
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (pad->priv->searchbar), 
                   GTK_WIDGET (searchentry));

/* Below does nothing (I mean haligh/valigh*/
// (meant to put searchentry with no more free space in search_bar 
// (to the left)
// I could also add a label Find but what for? I just want 
// GtkSearchEntry to occupy the whole GtkSearchBar apart for close btn
/* Nothing of that works */
//gtk_widget_set_halign (GTK_WIDGET (searchentry), GTK_ALIGN_START);
//gtk_widget_set_valign (GTK_WIDGET (searchentry), GTK_ALIGN_START);
gtk_search_bar_connect_entry (GTK_SEARCH_BAR (pad->priv->searchbar),
                              GTK_ENTRY (searchentry));

// Searchbar should appear in right-top corner of the overlay
// to not cover the text which is searched (assuming that first
// several lines most probably are short enough to not be covered)
/* So these line do work but only for the GtkSearchBar itself
   not got GtkSearchEntry inside of it) (/
gtk_widget_set_halign (GTK_WIDGET (pad->priv->searchbar), GTK_ALIGN_END);
gtk_widget_set_valign (GTK_WIDGET (pad->priv->searchbar),                        GTK_ALIGN_START);

// Jere a Just add a scroll with a text and a GtkSearchBar to a GtkOverlay
pad->priv->text_with_search_overlay = GTK_OVERLAY (gtk_overlay_new ());
gtk_overlay_add_overlay (pad->priv->text_with_search_overlay, pad->priv->scrollbar);
gtk_overlay_add_overlay (pad->priv->text_with_search_overlay, GTK_WIDGET (pad->priv->searchbar));
```

This works nicely. I'm just not able to customize gtk_search_bar. Do I have  not yo use gtk_search_bar and create my own vbox in the overlay for this to happen? This way there will be no gtk_search_bar at all, just my widget with gtk_search_entry an button, manually removing it.

Whas it now can be observed: https://imagebin.ca/v/4Uo7Bqi6Pv7J. I don't like empty space in the left corner  of the GtkSearchBar. Is it customizable or do I have to write my own search bar (like HBox with stuff). I can get rid of it by creating a Hbox,adding GtkSearchEnttry and a close button. But it will remove convenient function to show/hide it: gtk_search_bar_set_search_mode - TRUE/FALSE and I like that it exists

Is there a way to "style" the GtkSearchBar somehow. Maybe here:

```
gtk_search_bar_connect_entry (GTK_SEARCH_BAR (pad->priv->searchbar), GTK_ENTRY (searchentry)); ?
```

I'm doing trying to use halign/valign for the gtk_search_bar:

```
gtk_widget_set_halign (GTK_WIDGET (pad->priv->searchbar), GTK_ALIGN_END);
gtk_widget_set_valign (GTK_WIDGET (pad->priv->searchbar), GTK_ALIGN_START);
```

But doing so for gtk_search_entry:

```
gtk_widget_set_halign (GTK_WIDGET (searchentry), GTK_ALIGN_END);
gtk_widget_set_valign (GTK_WIDGET (searchentry), GTK_ALIGN_START);
```

does nothing

This works for GtkSearchBsr. how to use for elements inside gtk_search_bar? Is there other way then create their layout by hand?